# The material of the model in svf format is lost, and the internal transparency

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

The material inside the model is completely transparent. Is there any way to keep the model from being lost? Or what additional parameters need to be set for the svf format model
[External](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm6bT.png)
[Internal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxyvR.png)

Comment: From which software this model comes from ? Are you using double sided materials ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a side-effect of [back-face culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling). Basically, to optimize the rendering performance, the viewer does not render triangles facing away from the camera.

One way to work around this would be to force double-sided rendering in Forge Viewer using its APIs:

```js
viewer.prefs.set(Autodesk.Viewing.Private.Prefs3D.FORCE_DOUBLE_SIDED, true);
```

Or, as [@AlexAR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9365707/alexar) mentioned, you could try and add some "thickness" to the walls in the original authoring application that created this model.

Comment: Thanks, but the api doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Just tried it in one of my sample apps, and it is working fine. Note that the `viewer` variable should be a reference to the `Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D` class you instantiated somewhere in your application.

Comment: I am indeed using the GuiViewer3D instantiated object.But it still looks like this

Comment: In that case I'd suggest to share the sample model with us, either through some public link here (if this is not sensitive data), or by sending the link to our official Forge support alias `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` so that we could debug it on our side.